# How to default initialize a vector element?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, stdvector, push-back

Let's say I have a class `X` that does not have any type of constructor unless an implicit default constructor:

```
class X
{
  public:
    int value;

    X(void)     = default;

    X(int)      = delete;
    X(const X&) = delete;
    X(X&&)      = delete;
};
```

When I make a vector out of this, `std::vector<X>`, and try to `push_back(X())` or `emplace_back()` an element to it, the program will not compile because it tries to use the move constructor (from what I understand of the error description).

> C2280 'X::X(X &&)': attempting to reference a deleted function

How can I make `push_back` or `emplace_back` use the default constructor?

Comment: Resizing would require to move existing elements.

Comment: From [std::vector::emplace_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) "T (the container's element type) must meet the requirements of *MoveInsertable* and *EmplaceConstructible*."

Comment: @Jarod42 Not if you put an element at the back of a vector though, right? The other elements would stay still (right?)

Comment: Not when `capacity` is not great enough. and so another bigger buffer is used.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah right. So does this mean that when the capacity is too small, the vector tries to reallocate itself elsewhere on the heap?

Comment: @Jarod42 The capcacity doesn't affect the requirements though. Just to be clear.

Comment: _"the vector tries to reallocate itself elsewhere on the heap?"_ that's implementation defined. The standard doesn't even mention _"heap"_. But the requirements are defined in the standard and one requirement is a copy constructor.

Comment: "Yes". (and even if your capacity is good enough, code to handle it is still instantiated).

Comment: What do you mean with "code to handle it is still instantiated"?

Comment: Instantiating a class from template `std::vector` generates code containing a call of the copy constructor. Even though you wouldn't call the copy constructor at runtime the compiler or linker will break with an error. C++ is not a script language where code is evaluated at runtime. C++ is compiled and linked and these steps already evaluate the code.

Comment: This is a minimal version of your problem: https://wandbox.org/permlink/dCmRvADoN8CH2MmR `std::vector` requires a copy constructor even though you don't want to call it at runtime.

Comment: You can use a deque or a list instead of a vector. Neither deque nor list require moving elements for `emplace_back`.

Comment: @dyp Right, of course, I never even thought of that. Thanks!